# Firebase: Cloud Function Triggers: six hidden "_xxxxx" documents in new collections triggering cloud functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I recently upgraded my google cloud functions to Node.js 10. I've encountered strange occurrences of hidden documents in new collections triggering cloud functions. These are the documents:
_createTime
_fieldsProto
_readTime
_ref
_serializer
_updateTime

These document String names do not exist in my code.
but they do exist in the constructor of a DocumentSnapshot: [googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/document.js.html](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/document.js.html)

I have a cloud function that triggers for documents onCreate with example path ('followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{followerId}'). Three times now with new users and first creation of this sub-collection has this occurred.

As a temporary workaround, I told the function to ignore [followerId]'s that match these hidden document names. However, I have over 30 functions that trigger on document create, and I don't want to have this hack workaround permanently at the top of each of these functions.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any Idea what going on?

Here is my Flutter/Dart code to follow a user:

```
followUser(String followerId) async {
    await getUserRef(uid: followerId).get().then((doc) {
      if (!doc.exists) return;
      documentUpdate(
          docRef: getFollowersRef(fid: followerId, uid: currentUser.id),
          payload: {
             //PAYLOAD EXAMPLE:
            'notificationToken': currentUser.notificationToken, //String
            'username': currentUser.username, //String
            'ofUsername': doc.data['username'], //String
            'profileImgURL': currentUser.photoUrl, //String
            'timestamp': DateTime.now(),  //Timestamp
            'displayName': currentUser.displayName, //String
          });
      documentUpdate(
          docRef: getFollowingRef(uid: currentUser.id, fid: followerId),
          payload: {
            // follower data. Same as above but inverted for follower.
          });
    });
  }

documentUpdate({DocumentReference docRef, Map<String, dynamic> payload}) {
   return docRef.setData(payload, merge: true);
}
```

Snippet from index.js cloud function:

```
exports.onNewFollower = functions.firestore
    .document('/followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{followerId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const followerId = context.params.followerId;
        console.log(`uid: [${userId}], fid: [${followerId}]`);
        if (followerId == 'index' ||
            userId == '_ref' ||      //ADDED THIS AFTER FOR PREVENTION
            userId == '_fieldsPronto' ||
            userId == '_createTime' ||
            userId == '_readTime' ||
            userId == '_updateTime' ||
            userId == '_serializer' ||
            followerId == '_ref' ||
            followerId == '_fieldsPronto' ||
            followerId == '_createTime' ||
            followerId == '_readTime' ||
            followerId == '_updateTime' ||
            followerId == '_serializer')
          return await Promise.resolve(true);

        var promises = [];
        promises.push(db.collection('followers').doc(userId).collection('userFollowers').doc('index').set(
                { 'uids': { [followerId]: true } },
                { merge: true },
            )
        );
        promises.push(
            db.collection('following').doc(followerId).collection('userFollowing').doc('index').set(
                { 'uids': { [userId]: true } },
                { merge: true },
            )
        );
        promises.push(db.collection('activityFeed').doc(userId).collection('feedItems').doc(followerId).set(
            {
                timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                type: 'newFollower',
                userId: followerId,
                userProfileImg: snapshot.data().profileImgURL,
                username: snapshot.data().username,
                displayName: snapshot.data().displayName,
            }
        ));
        return await Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Here is an example of the cloud function console output when these odd documents are attempted. It is confusing to understand, but it is clear that these odd documents trigger after the one intended does. The cloud function throws errors because these odd documents don't contain the data the function requires to complete.

```
7:16:25.473 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:16:26.535 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [Du1orkZrykWJ1BL0kKOuj4HO0ji2], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:16:27.442 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 1971 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:17:14.663 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started 
7:17:14.677 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [_ref], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:17:14.684 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 21 ms, finished with status: 'error'
7:17:15.342 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:15.352 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 11 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:17:15.659 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:15.664 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [_createTime], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:17:15.666 PM
onNewFollower
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "username"). at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:251:15) at validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:610:22) at WriteBatch.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:9) at DocumentReference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:338:14) at exports.onNewFollower.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:842:99) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
7:17:15.667 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 31 ms, finished with status: 'error'
7:17:15.790 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:15.797 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 7 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:17:16.682 PM
onNewFollower
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "username"). at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:251:15) at validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:610:22) at WriteBatch.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:9) at DocumentReference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:338:14) at exports.onNewFollower.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:842:99) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
7:17:17.467 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:17.616 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:17.948 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:18.288 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:18.664 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [_readTime], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:17:19.069 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 1603 ms, finished with status: 'error'
7:17:19.363 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [_updateTime], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:17:19.430 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [_serializer], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:17:19.863 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 2247 ms, finished with status: 'error' 
7:17:19.878 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 1931 ms, finished with status: 'error'
7:17:19.960 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [_fieldsProto], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:17:20.089 PM
onNewFollower
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "username"). at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:251:15) at validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:610:22) at WriteBatch.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:9) at DocumentReference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:338:14) at exports.onNewFollower.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:842:99) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
7:17:20.417 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 2129 ms, finished with status: 'error'
7:17:20.923 PM
onNewFollower
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "username"). at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:251:15) at validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:610:22) at WriteBatch.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:9) at DocumentReference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:338:14) at exports.onNewFollower.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:842:99) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
7:17:20.928 PM
onNewFollower
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "username"). at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:251:15) at validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:610:22) at WriteBatch.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:9) at DocumentReference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:338:14) at exports.onNewFollower.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:842:99) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
7:17:21.428 PM
onNewFollower
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "username"). at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:251:15) at validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:610:22) at WriteBatch.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:9) at DocumentReference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:338:14) at exports.onNewFollower.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:842:99) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
7:17:36.561 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:36.572 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 11 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:17:37.567 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:37.581 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 15 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:17:41.263 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:41.370 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 108 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:17:42.070 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:17:42.853 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 785 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:24:25.667 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution started
7:24:26.775 PM
onNewFollower
uid: [ilxBwWHVDiVJ2iR4AsfIxrpIUgb2], fid: [LtiIcZ8rrphcEnyCWnieKvte6ln2]
7:24:27.567 PM
onNewFollower
Function execution took 1901 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

The document successfully written and the collection with none of the odd documents showing
[image: The document successfully written and the collection with none of the odd documents showing]

Comment: 1) node 10 does not work fundamentally any differently than node 8. 2) There are no such things as "hidden documents" in Firestore.  All documents are equally visible, no matter what their IDs are.  Without seeing your code and source data, there's not much we can do to diagnose whatever is going on here.  Please edit the question to be more clear about how you are able to reproduce the behavior, and what you're expecting instead.

Comment: Added the code for the follow function in Dart and the cloud function snippet. I can't see the problem being above the follow function because the 'getUserRef(fid:"_serializer", uid: currentUser.id)' document does not exist and would exit the function. This problem also only occurs on the first time creation of this subcollection.

Comment: "Do stuff" needs to be shown.  Please provide enough information that anyone can reproduce the problem and observe what you're also observing.

Comment: I recommend trying to reproduce the problem with just a minimal Cloud Function that logs the document IDs. If you can't reproduce it like that, add a minimal bit of code that might be causing the problem. Keep doing this until you have reproduced the problem, and update the query with only **that** code. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/document.js.html 
Here you can see each of those fields existing in the constructor of a document on firestore

Comment: If I knew more about the problem, I would share. I've narrowed down the code to these two exact points. In the dart code, it is impossible that a request would be sent to firestore with these hidden document names, and there is nowhere in the cloud function where they could appear. However, they exist in the constructor for document snapshots, which is my only clue that somehow when the documents are created, the cloud function triggers early on these items that should not trigger functions.

Comment: The issue also isn't consistently reproducible. The only change I've made in the past week was the change to Node.js 10, which is why i offered that information. This is why it leads me to believe it is a timing issue on firestore's end. But I'm at a loss for leads, hence why I came here to see if anyone has had a similar issue.

Comment: I know it's extremely bold to say this, but I think it's a firebase glitch

Comment: Just to confirm is not a problem of Cloud functions, is possible reproduce this behavior on an external environment? Also could be interesting you reproduce the issue using the emulator https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: I will try to reproduce with emulator. It is highly likely that the plugin "cloud_firestore" which connects flutter to firebase is broken. There have been countless issues with the open source plugin. For starters, Transactions are useless. I wonder if it might be packaging the document object incorrectly. But then it doesn't make sense to me that the 6 documents wouldn't exist in my firestore database. Unless firestore detects that these 6 documents are broken and removes them after the cloud function triggers. All I want for christmas if for google to build a plugin from Flutter to Firebase

Comment: I suggest paring your code samples down to show all the exact data you're working with.  Right now, you have variables whose values we can't see, and payloads that are missing.  Make sure that anyone can reproduce the behavior with the code you provide.  Also be clear in your question what exactly you are observing.  Show logs.  Share screenshots of data in the console.  We need to be able to observe what you are observing.

Comment: I added the console log output of the cloud function, an example of the payload with types associated, as well as a screenshot of the intended document successfully written in the database.

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that the cloud function fails on the 'username' field. Which means that the 'profileImgURL' data exists in these odd documents. Or they exist at the time of the cloud function trigger... I dunno, pulling at straw here.

Comment: Actually, there is a flutter plugin for firebase if you need I take a look at the official support. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add-flutterfire-plugins

Comment: Turns out it is an issue with the FlutterFire plugin... I wish google just managed the bridge between their products. FlutterFire has brought me so much pain over this project. Transactions are useless and random stability issues pop up in each update.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this issue to the FlutterFire team. They've informed me that this is in fact an issue with the plugin and that the fix will be rolled out in the coming updates to the package...